# Automatize One-Time-Password Authentication

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-16.04, two-factor-authentication

It is possible to login to remote host without password, i.e., `ssh-copy-id <host>`.

However, I need to enter One-Time Password (OTP) every time I log into a remote host. How can I skip this OTP part? Is is possible to store a ssh session on my PC for limited time?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.02

Comment: [how to disable SSH login with password for some users?](http://serverfault.com/questions/285800/how-to-disable-ssh-login-with-password-for-some-users) might be relevant as it might allow you to set it up in a way that this special user has other options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The point of "second factor" is that it is something different than a password and therefore it should not be stored on the same device as the first factor is.

One time password is interactive challenge-response so it is not advisable to automate it (for sake of security).

But ... there is `ControlMaster` feature with `ControlPersist` option in OpenSSH, which does something that might solve your problems. It allows you to issue multiple ssh sessions using single TCP connection and preserve this master connection for some time after the original ends.

How to do that? Store this configuration snippet in the `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host your-server
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/control-master-%C
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPersist 5m
```

But make sure that the created sockets in `~/.ssh/control-master-%C` are not accessible by any other user on your system, because in that case they would be able to connect to your server too!