# How to have pfSense append an RFC 6238 suffix to client passwords when connecting to OpenVPN server?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, pfsense

I want to setup pfSense to bridge two networks using OpenVPN.

But due to non-security reasons, [and not security reasons](https://superuser.com/a/1198205/8169), it is required that the user's password have a 6-digit suffix (that follows the RFC 6238 hashing algorithm, i.e. HMAC_SHA1) appended to their password.

The OpenVPN client must then send that revised password when logging into the pfSense OpenVPN server:

- **Username**: `billg`
- **Password**: `Tr0ub4dor&3`﻿`602738` (i.e. `[password]`﻿`[6-digit OTP]`)

The problem is that one of the inputs to the RFC 6238 hashing algorithm is the current time (measured in ticks that last 30-seconds each); which you get from your favorite RFC 6238 tool:

[image]

## Test

You can sorta make it work sometimes if you manage to:

- enter in the password + OPT in the client configuration page

  [image]
- and save it
- and hope it connects

all within the same 30 seconds inside the pfSense WebGUI. And that works:

[image]

But if the pfSense client, or the OpenVPN server (which is also pfSense), get disconnected, then the pfSense site-to-site cannot re-establish a connection.

## Research Effort

pfSense, when acting as a VPN Server, using a local RADIUS server, can configure *users* to require 2FA [with a time-based one time password](https://vorkbaard.nl/how-to-set-up-openvpn-with-google-authenticator-on-pfsense/):

[image]

But that saved your TOTP secret in pfSense is so:

- a *client* can connect from the outside into the local server
- but not so a *client* can cannect from the local server to the outside

I hoped that there would be an option in the *local* **User Manager** to:

- in addition being able to configure a user's username/password
- and their certificate
- and the private key for their certificate
- and SSH keys
- and IPsec pre-shared keys

they'd be able to include the ability to enter secret for the password-suffix generator.

But they don't.

## The Question

How can i have pfSense include a 6-digit password suffix, generated using the RFC 6238 hashing algorithm?

*Note:* Obviously what i'm describing is not 2FA, because there is no second factor.